# How to consistently determine how many digits my round.random.uniform has?

Tags: python, random

This code:

```
import random

while True:
    thing = str(round(random.uniform(1,3), 3))
    print(thing)
```

Is not consistently generating numbers with 3 decimals, giving me sometimes numbers with only 2 decimals.

Output example:

```
1.575
2.035
2.864
2.118
1.069
2.36
1.092
1.948
2.54
2.224
2.318
1.713
1.819
2.717
1.171
2.918
3.0
1.23
2.487
```

I'm able to fix this creating a routine to check the length of my number, and then I append a string of another random generated integer. Like

```
if len(thing) < 5:
    thing = thing + str(2)
```

I would like to know, however, how I can set parameters to generate random number with fixed lengths at all times.

Thanks in advance!

@Edit:
Thanks to Harry and Peter, a solution was found. I'm controlling the length of my number with:

```
thing = round(random.uniform(1,3), 3)
hora = str(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
pack = '{:.3f}'.format(thing) + ',' + hora
pack = str(pack)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating numbers with three decimal places all the time, it's just that in some cases one or more of those decimal places is `0`. By default `print` doesn't display trailing 0s after the decimal point. For example, it might generate the number 2.360, but `print` trims it to `2.36`. If you want to always show the numbers at a certain number of decimal places, you can use a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```py
print('{:.3f}'.format(thing))
```

That would print `2.360` in the example I just gave.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the answer, Harry. Can I use this to set a variable? The code I used was to print, and then I see the format coming in handy, but the ultimate goal is to have a variable be given a number with 3 decimals. Thanks again!

Comment: Clarifying the doubt: can I use the {:.3f}'.format() for, let's say, send a message to a socket with this number as a content?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, `'{:.3f}'.format(...)` just returns a string like any other.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to generate a random integer in a range multiplied by a power of 10 (e.g., 1000), then divide the random integer by that same power of 10:

```
random.randrange(1000, 3000) / 1000
```

But note that the resulting number is a base-2 floating-point number, which is not an ideal way to store decimal numbers.  However, Python has a standard library that supports decimal numbers; to generate a random decimal number, simply import `decimal` and create a decimal from the random integer as follows:

```
from decimal import Decimal
frac = Decimal(1)/Decimal(1000)
Decimal(random.randrange(1000, 3000)) * frac
```

(The `decimal` library won't always display the same number of places after the decimal point by just dividing by 1000.)

Comment: Really clever solution, just as I was looking for (: yours and Harry's answer together may give me the perfect solution indeed. Thank, Peter!

Comment: If you do `Decimal(random.randrange(1000, 3000)) * Decimal('0.001')`, you *will* always see the trailing zeros.

Comment: @MarkDickinson : Used `Decimal(1)/Decimal(1000)`, which leads to the same result as `Decimal('0.001')` and is easily transferable to other powers of 10.

Comment: Yep, but now compare `Decimal(20) / Decimal(1000)` with `Decimal(20) * Decimal('0.001')`. The latter gives three digits after the point, including the extra zero: `Decimal('0.020')`. The former just gives `Decimal('0.02')`. That's what I meant by "you will always see the trailing zeros".

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `n / Decimal('1e3')`, which also gives the desired effect.